# Stuck with view scrolling to follow sprite

Tags: java, android, canvas, scroll, sprite

I'm very new to programming and am currently trying to make a simple game for android. The problem I'm having is the way the view is scrolling. By my logic, I believe the sprite should stay in the center of the screen, but it doesn't. The view does follow the sprite, but not at the same speed if that makes sense. As in the view kind of lags behind. It's not jumpy so I know it's not running slowly. What surprises me though is I'm setting my scrolling rectangle equal to player x location - display width, and then same for the y axis. So What I'm hoping you guys can help me out with is figure out why the sprite isn't staying in the center of the view. Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Thanks.

```
private static Rect displayRect = null; //rect we display to
private Rect scrollRect = null; //rect we scroll over our bitmap with

Display display = getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay();
displayWidth = display.getWidth();             
displayHeight = display.getHeight();   

displayRect = new Rect(0, 0, displayWidth, displayHeight);
scrollRect = new Rect(0, 0, displayWidth, displayHeight);
```

//Setting the new upper left corner of the scrolling rectangle

```
    newScrollRectX = ((int)player.getXLocation() - (displayWidth/2));
    newScrollRectY = ((int)player.getYLocation() - (displayHeight/2));
```

//This is in my onDraw method, so it updates right before the player is drawn

```
    scrollRect.set(newScrollRectX, newScrollRectY,
    newScrollRectX + displayWidth, newScrollRectY + displayHeight);
```

//bmLargeImage is a 1440X1440 background

```
    canvas.drawBitmap(bmLargeImage, scrollRect, displayRect, paint);

canvas.drawBitmap(player.getBitmap(),(float)player.getX(player.getSpeedX()),     (float)player.getY(player.getSpeedY()), null);
```

Answer (score 0):

My first guess would be you are using integer calculations and should use floating point calculations instead.

```
int test = 10 / 3; // == 3
float test2 = 10 / 3.0; // == 3.33333...
```

This would explain the 'jumping'.

---

Beware, I am not certain whether all android phones have [FPUs](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Floating-point_unit). You might have to use [fixed point calculations](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fixed-point_arithmetic) instead to guarantee proper performance.

Comment: I appreciate the quick response. It's not jumping. The sprite doesn't stay in the middle of the screen like I thought this logic would return. I changed to floats, same problem : /

Comment: No luck. I don't know if this helps to picture the problem, but the sprite seems to move faster than the background image. Either I'm not understanding the concept, or there's something very simple wrong. With this logic I'm picturing the sprite staying in the middle of the screen, so it would appear to not be moving at all, except for the background giving the appearance of movement.

Comment: Well for one, I feel some code is missing to understand the bigger picture. But, if you want to display the sprite in the middle of the screen, then why do you use `getX()` and `getY()` and the getSpeed() calls? Just draw the bitmap on the middle of the screen?

Comment: Thanks for your patience. I started out with a sprite moving around depending on where the finger was dragged. I then decided I wanted a larger map, one with a scrolling view. I still want to keep the movement of the character. I have a 1440X1440 background, but only a small view. I want the character to stay in the middle of the view as the user moves the character, simulating moving on the larger background. Makes sense when I think about it, I'm not thinking incredibly clearly at the moment though. Hope this helps clear up the confusion